# function to compare 2 matrices

Tags: php, arrays

i got matrix and i want compare it if the elements inside it equal to another matrix in example

i got this

```
$p = array();
$p[] = array(1, 3);
$p[] = array(1, 1);
```

**compare with**

```
$q = array();
$q[] = array(1, 0);
$q[] = array(0, 1);
```

if they equal each other , echo true ..

i try this

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($p) - 1; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j <= count($q) - 1; $j++) {
        if ($p[$i] == $q[$j]) {

            // this only for 1 elements , i want check all elements
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the php match libraries. You will probably find something implementing matrice arithmetic.

Comment: Please try like this var_dump($p == $q);

Comment: var_dump work but it give me bool(true) or bool(false) ,,

Comment: `var_dump` just shows you the result, `true` or `false` is exactly what you want. `==` is doing the real task you're looking for.

Comment: if (var_dump($p === $q)) {
                echo "it's Ideantty Matrix ";
                print_r($r);
            } else {
                echo "it's Not Ideantty Matrix ";
                print_r($r);
            }

this is what i got bool(true) it's Not Ideantty Matrix Array

Comment: `if ($p == $q)`! `var_dump` is just for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

no need to compare or anything

this fixed my problem

```
    if ($p == $q){
        Echo "This Matrix Identity <Br />";
        print_r($r);
    }
    else{
        Echo "This Matrix Is Not Identity <Br />";
        print_r($r);
    }
}
```